# Web-based file manager with ability to check-out and check-in files

Tags: open-source, web-apps, file-management

I am looking for a simple open source web-based file manager that can do the following:

- List files
- Allow logged-in users to check-out a file (i.e. download), whereupon the file will be "locked" and other users will be prevented from checking-in modified versions of the file.
- Allow logged-in users to check-in a file (i.e. upload) only if the file is currently checked-out by that user.
- Allow users to download files without checking-out files.

Comment: Did you try [JCE](https://www.joomlacontenteditor.net/) / Joomla?

Answer (score 1):

[Alfresco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alfresco_Software) does exactly this, and is open source.

Users can browse files, download or read online the files they want, and to edit a file they must "checkout", edit, then "checkin", at which points everyone will be see in the new version.

It is simple to use, but installing it may take about an hour even if you are used to installing web applications.

How to edit files: https://docs.alfresco.com/content-services/7.0/tutorial/video/content/#edit-files

[image]